# Movie with a robot in a female skin who is discovered by her boyfriend

Tags: story-identification, robots

I’m trying to find the title for a movie or possibly a tv show a saw as a kid. I remember it being in the mid 90s to early 2000’s.

It was about a robot that had female skin and was later discovered by the boyfriend and I want to say bubble gum had some kind of effect on the robots. Sorry I don’t have much to go off of and I searched every where and can’t find anything.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When you say the robot "was discovered" do you mean that the boyfriend didn't know she was a robot and found that out?  Was this live-action or animated?  What language was it in?

Comment: I just found what I was looking for. It was actually aliens instead of robots. The movie is “My favorite Martian” with Christopher Lloyd.